# Disabled Submit button after uncheck from a nested checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I had try to find the solution here with similar question, but none of the solution can fixed my problem. I'm Currently having a problem with disable the submit button whenever i uncheck all checkbox.

Basically my website have few checkbox, when user tick any of the checkbox the disabled submit button will become able to submit. But when user unticks the checkbox, my submit button won't disabled back.

Here is my sample HTML Code :

```
<form action="" id="myform" name="myform" class="myform">
<div class="anchor">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="All Master" data-name="All Master" id="myCheckBox0" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> All Kedai Kiosk On Master Mode</label>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Selangor" data-name="Selangor"  id="myCheckBox1" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Selangor</label>
                    <ul id="navlist">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<li><label><input type="checkbox"  data-id="Petaling Jaya" data-name="Petaling Jaya" id="myCheckBox2" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Petaling Jaya&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="1" data-id="Kiosk 1" data-name="Kiosk 1" id="myCheckBox3" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 1&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>
                            </ul>                           
                        </li>

                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Puchong" data-name="Puchong" id="myCheckBox4" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Puchong&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="2" data-id="Kiosk 2" data-name="Kiosk 2" id="myCheckBox5" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 2&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li> 
                            </ul>
                        </li>   
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox"  data-id="Subang Hub" data-name="Subang Hub" id="myCheckBox6" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Subang Hub&nbsp;</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="5" data-id="Kiosk 5" data-name="Kiosk 5" id="myCheckBox7" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 5&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li> 
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="20" data-id="Kiosk 20" data-name="Kiosk 20" id="myCheckBox8" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 20&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Bangi" data-name="Bangi" id="myCheckBox9" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Bangi&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="7" data-id="Kiosk 7" data-name="Kiosk 7" id="myCheckBox10" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 7&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>    
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="8" data-id="Kiosk 8" data-name="Kiosk 8" id="myCheckBox11" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 8&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Shah Alam" data-name="Shah Alam" id="myCheckBox12" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Shah Alam&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="9" data-id="Kiosk 9" data-name="Kiosk 9" id="myCheckBox13" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 9&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>    
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="10" data-id="Kiosk 10" data-name="Kiosk 10" id="myCheckBox14" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 10&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>   
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox"  data-id="Cheras" data-name="Cheras" id="myCheckBox15" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Cheras&nbsp;</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="11" data-id="Kiosk 11" data-name="Kiosk 11" id="myCheckBox16" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 11&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>    
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="12" data-id="Kiosk 12" data-name="Kiosk 12" id="myCheckBox17" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 12&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox"  data-id="Banting" data-name="Banting" id="myCheckBox18" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Banting</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="13" data-id="Kiosk 13" data-name="Kiosk 13" id="myCheckBox19" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 13&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>    
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="14" data-id="Kiosk 14" data-name="Kiosk 14" id="myCheckBox20" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 14&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>   
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox"  data-id="Rawang" data-name="Rawang" id="myCheckBox21" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Rawang</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="15" data-id="Kiosk 15" data-name="Kiosk 15" id="myCheckBox22" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 15&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>    
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="16" data-id="Kiosk 16" data-name="Kiosk 16" id="myCheckBox23" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 16&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox"  data-id="Pelabuhan Klang" data-name="Pelabuhan Klang" id="myCheckBox24" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Pelabuhan Klang</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="17" data-id="Kiosk 17" data-name="Kiosk 17" id="myCheckBox25" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 17&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>    
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="18" data-id="Kiosk 18" data-name="Kiosk 18" id="myCheckBox26" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 18&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>   
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox"  data-id="Sungai Besar" data-name="Sungai Besar" id="myCheckBox27" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Sungai Besar</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="19" data-id="Kiosk 19" data-name="Kiosk 19" id="myCheckBox28" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 19&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>    
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox"  data-id="Kuala Selangor" data-name="Kuala Selangor" id="myCheckBox29" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kuala Selangor</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="21" data-id="Kiosk 21" data-name="Kiosk 21" id="myCheckBox30" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 21&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>    
                            </ul>
                        </li>   
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Sepang" data-name="Sepang" id="myCheckBox31" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Sepang</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="22" data-id="Kiosk 22" data-name="Kiosk 22" id="myCheckBox32" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 22&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>    
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Kajang" data-name="Kajang" id="myCheckBox33" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kajang</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="23" data-id="Kiosk 23" data-name="Kiosk 23" id="myCheckBox34" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> &nbsp;Kiosk 23&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></li>    
                            </ul>
                        </li>       
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <hr/>
                <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Putrajaya" data-name="Putrajaya" id="myCheckBox35" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Putrajaya</label>
                    <ul id="navlist">
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="24" data-id="Kiosk 24" data-name="Kiosk 24" id="myCheckBox36" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 24</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <hr/>
                <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Kuala Lumpur" data-name="Kuala Lumpur" id="myCheckBox37" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kuala Lumpur</label>
                    <ul id="navlist">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Kepong" data-name="Kepong" id="myCheckBox38" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kepong</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="26" data-id="Kiosk 26" data-name="Kiosk 26" id="myCheckBox39" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 26</label></li>
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="27" data-id="Kiosk 27" data-name="Kiosk 27" id="myCheckBox40" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 27</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Taman Melawati" data-name="Taman Melawati" id="myCheckBox41" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Taman Melawati</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="28" data-id="Kiosk 28" data-name="Kiosk 28" id="myCheckBox42" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 28</label></li>
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="29" data-id="Kiosk 29" data-name="Kiosk 29" id="myCheckBox43" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 29</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="UTC Pudu" data-name="UTC Pudu" id="myCheckBox44" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> UTC Pudu</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="30" data-id="Kiosk 30" data-name="Kiosk 30" id="myCheckBox45" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 30</label></li>
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="31" data-id="Kiosk 31" data-name="Kiosk 31" id="myCheckBox46" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 31</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Dua Sentral" data-name="Dua Sentral" id="myCheckBox47" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Dua Sentral</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="32" data-id="Kiosk 32" data-name="Kiosk 32" id="myCheckBox48" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 32</label></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Jalan Klang Lama" data-name="Jalan Klang Lama" id="myCheckBox49" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Jalan Klang Lama</label>
                            <ul>
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="33" data-id="Kiosk 33" data-name="Kiosk 33" id="myCheckBox50" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 33</label></li>
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="34" data-id="Kiosk 34" data-name="Kiosk 34" id="myCheckBox51" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 34</label></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <hr/>
                <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Pahang" data-name="Pahang" id="myCheckBox52" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Pahang</label>
                    <ul id="navlist">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Kuantan" data-name="Kuantan" id="myCheckBox53" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kuantan</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="35" data-id="Kiosk 35" data-name="Kiosk 35" id="myCheckBox54" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 35</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="UTC Kuantan" data-name="UTC Kuantan" id="myCheckBox55" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> UTC Kuantan</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="36" data-id="Kiosk 36" data-name="Kiosk 36" id="myCheckBox56" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 36</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Temerloh" data-name="Temerloh" id="myCheckBox57" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Temerloh</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="37" data-id="Kiosk 37" data-name="Kiosk 37" id="myCheckBox58" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 37</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Bentong" data-name="Bentong" id="myCheckBox59" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Bentong</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="6" data-id="Kiosk 6" data-name="Kiosk 6" id="myCheckBox60" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 6</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <hr/>
                <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Perak" data-name="Perak" id="myCheckBox61" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Perak</label>
                    <ul id="navlist">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Ipoh" data-name="Ipoh" id="myCheckBox62" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Ipoh</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="38" data-id="Kiosk 38" data-name="Kiosk 38" id="myCheckBox63" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 38</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="UTC Ipoh" data-name="UTC Ipoh" id="myCheckBox64" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> UTC Ipoh</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="39" data-id="Kiosk 39" data-name="Kiosk 39" id="myCheckBox65" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 39</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Taiping" data-name="Taiping" id="myCheckBox66" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Taiping</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="40" data-id="Kiosk 40" data-name="Kiosk 40" id="myCheckBox67" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 40</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Teluk Intan" data-name="Teluk Intan" id="myCheckBox68" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Teluk Intan</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="41" data-id="Kiosk 41" data-name="Kiosk 41" id="myCheckBox69" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 41</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Sri Manjung" data-name="Sri Manjung" id="myCheckBox70" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Sri Manjung</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="42" data-id="Kiosk 42" data-name="Kiosk 42" id="myCheckBox71" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 42</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <hr/>
                <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Kedah" data-name="Kedah" id="myCheckBox72" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kedah</label>
                    <ul id="navlist">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Alor Setar" data-name="Alor Setar" id="myCheckBox73" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Alor Setar</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="43" data-id="Kiosk 43" data-name="Kiosk 43" id="myCheckBox74" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 43</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="UTC Alor Setar" data-name="UTC Alor Setar" id="myCheckBox75" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> UTC Alor Setar</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="44" data-id="Kiosk 44" data-name="Kiosk 44" id="myCheckBox76" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 44</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Sungai Petani" data-name="Sungai Petani" id="myCheckBox77" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Sungai Petani</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="45" data-id="Kiosk 45" data-name="Kiosk 45" id="myCheckBox78" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 45</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Kulim" data-name="Kulim" id="myCheckBox79" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kulim</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="46" data-id="Kiosk 46" data-name="Kiosk 46" id="myCheckBox80" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 46</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <hr/>
                <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Pulau Pinang" data-name="Pulau Pinang" id="myCheckBox81" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Pulau Pinang</label>
                    <ul id="navlist">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Seberang Jaya" data-name="Seberang Jaya" id="myCheckBox82" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Seberang Jaya</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="47" data-id="Kiosk 47" data-name="Kiosk 47" id="myCheckBox83" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 47</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Pulau Pinang" data-name="Pulau Pinang" id="myCheckBox84" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Pulau Pinang</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="48" data-id="Kiosk 48" data-name="Kiosk 48" id="myCheckBox85" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 48</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Nibong Tebal" data-name="Nibong Tebal" id="myCheckBox86" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Nibong Tebal</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="49" data-id="Kiosk 49" data-name="Kiosk 49" id="myCheckBox87" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 49</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <hr/>
                <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Melaka" data-name="Melaka" id="myCheckBox88" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Melaka</label>
                    <ul id="navlist">
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Bandar Melaka" data-name="Bandar Melaka" id="myCheckBox89" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Bandar Melaka</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="50" data-id="Kiosk 50" data-name="Kiosk 50" id="myCheckBox90" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 50</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="UTC Melaka" data-name="UTC Melaka" id="myCheckBox91" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> UTC Melaka</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="51" data-id="Kiosk 51" data-name="Kiosk 51" id="myCheckBox92" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 51</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="TNB Jasin" data-name="TNB Jasin" id="myCheckBox93" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> TNB Jasin</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="25" data-id="Kiosk 25" data-name="Kiosk 25" id="myCheckBox94" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 25</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <hr/>
                <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Perlis" data-name="Perlis" id="myCheckBox95" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Perlis</label>
                    <ul id="navlist">
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="52" data-id="Kiosk 52" data-name="Kiosk 52" id="myCheckBox96" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 52</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <hr/>
                <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Negeri Sembilan" data-name="Negeri Sembilan" id="myCheckBox97" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Negeri Sembilan</label>
                    <ul id="navlist">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Seremban" data-name="Seremban" id="myCheckBox98" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Seremban</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="53" data-id="Kiosk 53" data-name="Kiosk 53" id="myCheckBox99" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 53</label></li>                                                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Nilai" data-name="Nilai" id="myCheckBox100" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Nilai</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="54" data-id="Kiosk 54" data-name="Kiosk 54" id="myCheckBox101" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 54</label></li>                                                             
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <hr/>
                <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Kelantan" data-name="Kelantan" id="myCheckBox122" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kelantan</label>
                    <ul id="navlist">
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="62" data-id="Kiosk 62" data-name="Kiosk 62" id="myCheckBox123" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 62</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <hr/>
                <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Terengganu" data-name="Terengganu" id="myCheckBox124" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Terengganu</label>
                    <ul id="navlist">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Terengganu" data-name="Terengganu" id="myCheckBox125" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Terengganu</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="63" data-id="Kiosk 63" data-name="Kiosk 63" id="myCheckBox126" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 63</label></li>                                                             
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-id="Kemaman" data-name="Kemaman" id="myCheckBox127" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kemaman</label>
                            <ul >
                                <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="64" data-id="Kiosk 64" data-name="Kiosk 64" id="myCheckBox128" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);"/> Kiosk 64</label></li>                                                             
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <p>Selected items (readable): <span class="selected-readable" id="selected-readable"></span></p>
    <p>Selected items: <span class="selected">[]</span></p>
    <p>Excepted items: <span class="excepted">[]</span></p>
</div>                  
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="hidden" name="modeType" value="0"> 
    <button id="testing" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return submitForm()" disabled>Submit </button>
</div>
<div id="myResponse"></div>
```

Here is my JavaScript - I'm trying to play around with the submit, disable & enable function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function checkDisabled(yourSubmitButton) {

    for (var i = 0; i <= 128; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById("myCheckBox" + i).checked == true) {
            yourSubmitButton.disabled = false;
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i <= 128; i++) {

        if (document.getElementById("myICheckBox" + i).checked == true) {
            yourSubmitButton.disabled = false;

        }
    }

};
```

I had try few ways but it have some problem through. And it was a nested checkbox, I'm still new to JavaScript so I not really sure am i doing it on correct way or not. Due to limitation of word count in Stackoverflow, I had removed some of the checkbox code which is duplicate.

Comment: you're not using jQuery at all...

Comment: @I.G.Pascual Sorry, miss-tag i had removed it.

Comment: you should familiar with http://jsfiddle.net, http://codepen.io, etc for this questions purpose, it makes us life a lot easier

Comment: @I.G.Pascual Did you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/a836pde7/   But my nested checkbox become can't function

Comment: your code sample is way tooooo( like the way Google shows Goooooo......gle in pagination ) large.

Comment: please @MarcusTan format the html of the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like

```js
function checkDisabled(yourSubmitButton) {

  yourSubmitButton.disabled = true;

  var els = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i].checked == true) {
      yourSubmitButton.disabled = false;
      break;
    }
  }

};
```

```html
<form action="" id="myform" name="myform" class="myform">
  <div class="anchor">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-id="All Master" data-name="All Master" id="myCheckBox0" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />All Kedai Kiosk On Master Mode</label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" data-id="Selangor" data-name="Selangor" id="myCheckBox1" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Selangor</label>
            <ul id="navlist">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Petaling Jaya" data-name="Petaling Jaya" id="myCheckBox2" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Petaling Jaya&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="1" data-id="Kiosk 1" data-name="Kiosk 1" id="myCheckBox3" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 1&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Puchong" data-name="Puchong" id="myCheckBox4" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Puchong&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="2" data-id="Kiosk 2" data-name="Kiosk 2" id="myCheckBox5" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />&nbsp;Kiosk 2&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Subang Hub" data-name="Subang Hub" id="myCheckBox6" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />&nbsp;Subang Hub&nbsp;</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="5" data-id="Kiosk 5" data-name="Kiosk 5" id="myCheckBox7" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />&nbsp;Kiosk 5&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="20" data-id="Kiosk 20" data-name="Kiosk 20" id="myCheckBox8" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />&nbsp;Kiosk 20&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Shah Alam" data-name="Shah Alam" id="myCheckBox12" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />&nbsp;Shah Alam&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="9" data-id="Kiosk 9" data-name="Kiosk 9" id="myCheckBox13" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />&nbsp;Kiosk 9&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="10" data-id="Kiosk 10" data-name="Kiosk 10" id="myCheckBox14" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />&nbsp;Kiosk 10&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Cheras" data-name="Cheras" id="myCheckBox15" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />&nbsp;Cheras&nbsp;</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="11" data-id="Kiosk 11" data-name="Kiosk 11" id="myCheckBox16" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />&nbsp;Kiosk 11&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="12" data-id="Kiosk 12" data-name="Kiosk 12" id="myCheckBox17" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />&nbsp;Kiosk 12&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Pelabuhan Klang" data-name="Pelabuhan Klang" id="myCheckBox24" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Pelabuhan Klang</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="17" data-id="Kiosk 17" data-name="Kiosk 17" id="myCheckBox25" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />&nbsp;Kiosk 17&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="18" data-id="Kiosk 18" data-name="Kiosk 18" id="myCheckBox26" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />&nbsp;Kiosk 18&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Kuala Selangor" data-name="Kuala Selangor" id="myCheckBox29" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kuala Selangor</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="21" data-id="Kiosk 21" data-name="Kiosk 21" id="myCheckBox30" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />&nbsp;Kiosk 21&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Sepang" data-name="Sepang" id="myCheckBox31" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Sepang</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="22" data-id="Kiosk 22" data-name="Kiosk 22" id="myCheckBox32" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />&nbsp;Kiosk 22&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Kajang" data-name="Kajang" id="myCheckBox33" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kajang</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="23" data-id="Kiosk 23" data-name="Kiosk 23" id="myCheckBox34" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />&nbsp;Kiosk 23&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <hr/>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" data-id="Putrajaya" data-name="Putrajaya" id="myCheckBox35" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Putrajaya</label>
            <ul id="navlist">
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="24" data-id="Kiosk 24" data-name="Kiosk 24" id="myCheckBox36" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 24</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <hr/>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" data-id="Kuala Lumpur" data-name="Kuala Lumpur" id="myCheckBox37" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kuala Lumpur</label>
            <ul id="navlist">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Kepong" data-name="Kepong" id="myCheckBox38" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kepong</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="26" data-id="Kiosk 26" data-name="Kiosk 26" id="myCheckBox39" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 26</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="27" data-id="Kiosk 27" data-name="Kiosk 27" id="myCheckBox40" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 27</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Taman Melawati" data-name="Taman Melawati" id="myCheckBox41" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Taman Melawati</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="28" data-id="Kiosk 28" data-name="Kiosk 28" id="myCheckBox42" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 28</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="29" data-id="Kiosk 29" data-name="Kiosk 29" id="myCheckBox43" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 29</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="UTC Pudu" data-name="UTC Pudu" id="myCheckBox44" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />UTC Pudu</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="30" data-id="Kiosk 30" data-name="Kiosk 30" id="myCheckBox45" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 30</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="31" data-id="Kiosk 31" data-name="Kiosk 31" id="myCheckBox46" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 31</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Dua Sentral" data-name="Dua Sentral" id="myCheckBox47" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Dua Sentral</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="32" data-id="Kiosk 32" data-name="Kiosk 32" id="myCheckBox48" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 32</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Jalan Klang Lama" data-name="Jalan Klang Lama" id="myCheckBox49" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Jalan Klang Lama</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="33" data-id="Kiosk 33" data-name="Kiosk 33" id="myCheckBox50" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 33</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="34" data-id="Kiosk 34" data-name="Kiosk 34" id="myCheckBox51" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 34</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <hr/>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" data-id="Pahang" data-name="Pahang" id="myCheckBox52" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Pahang</label>
            <ul id="navlist">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Kuantan" data-name="Kuantan" id="myCheckBox53" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kuantan</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="35" data-id="Kiosk 35" data-name="Kiosk 35" id="myCheckBox54" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 35</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="UTC Kuantan" data-name="UTC Kuantan" id="myCheckBox55" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />UTC Kuantan</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="36" data-id="Kiosk 36" data-name="Kiosk 36" id="myCheckBox56" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 36</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Temerloh" data-name="Temerloh" id="myCheckBox57" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Temerloh</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="37" data-id="Kiosk 37" data-name="Kiosk 37" id="myCheckBox58" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 37</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <hr/>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" data-id="Perak" data-name="Perak" id="myCheckBox61" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Perak</label>
            <ul id="navlist">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Ipoh" data-name="Ipoh" id="myCheckBox62" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Ipoh</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="38" data-id="Kiosk 38" data-name="Kiosk 38" id="myCheckBox63" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 38</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="UTC Ipoh" data-name="UTC Ipoh" id="myCheckBox64" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />UTC Ipoh</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="39" data-id="Kiosk 39" data-name="Kiosk 39" id="myCheckBox65" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 39</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Taiping" data-name="Taiping" id="myCheckBox66" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Taiping</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="40" data-id="Kiosk 40" data-name="Kiosk 40" id="myCheckBox67" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 40</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Teluk Intan" data-name="Teluk Intan" id="myCheckBox68" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Teluk Intan</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="41" data-id="Kiosk 41" data-name="Kiosk 41" id="myCheckBox69" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 41</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Sri Manjung" data-name="Sri Manjung" id="myCheckBox70" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Sri Manjung</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="42" data-id="Kiosk 42" data-name="Kiosk 42" id="myCheckBox71" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 42</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <hr/>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" data-id="Kedah" data-name="Kedah" id="myCheckBox72" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kedah</label>
            <ul id="navlist">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Alor Setar" data-name="Alor Setar" id="myCheckBox73" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Alor Setar</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="43" data-id="Kiosk 43" data-name="Kiosk 43" id="myCheckBox74" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 43</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="UTC Alor Setar" data-name="UTC Alor Setar" id="myCheckBox75" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />UTC Alor Setar</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="44" data-id="Kiosk 44" data-name="Kiosk 44" id="myCheckBox76" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 44</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Sungai Petani" data-name="Sungai Petani" id="myCheckBox77" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Sungai Petani</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="45" data-id="Kiosk 45" data-name="Kiosk 45" id="myCheckBox78" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 45</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Kulim" data-name="Kulim" id="myCheckBox79" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kulim</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="46" data-id="Kiosk 46" data-name="Kiosk 46" id="myCheckBox80" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 46</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <hr/>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" data-id="Pulau Pinang" data-name="Pulau Pinang" id="myCheckBox81" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Pulau Pinang</label>
            <ul id="navlist">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Seberang Jaya" data-name="Seberang Jaya" id="myCheckBox82" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Seberang Jaya</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="47" data-id="Kiosk 47" data-name="Kiosk 47" id="myCheckBox83" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 47</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Pulau Pinang" data-name="Pulau Pinang" id="myCheckBox84" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Pulau Pinang</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="48" data-id="Kiosk 48" data-name="Kiosk 48" id="myCheckBox85" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 48</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Nibong Tebal" data-name="Nibong Tebal" id="myCheckBox86" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Nibong Tebal</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="49" data-id="Kiosk 49" data-name="Kiosk 49" id="myCheckBox87" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 49</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <hr/>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" data-id="Melaka" data-name="Melaka" id="myCheckBox88" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Melaka</label>
            <ul id="navlist">
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Bandar Melaka" data-name="Bandar Melaka" id="myCheckBox89" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Bandar Melaka</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="50" data-id="Kiosk 50" data-name="Kiosk 50" id="myCheckBox90" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 50</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="UTC Melaka" data-name="UTC Melaka" id="myCheckBox91" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />UTC Melaka</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="51" data-id="Kiosk 51" data-name="Kiosk 51" id="myCheckBox92" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 51</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="TNB Jasin" data-name="TNB Jasin" id="myCheckBox93" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />TNB Jasin</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="25" data-id="Kiosk 25" data-name="Kiosk 25" id="myCheckBox94" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 25</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <hr/>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" data-id="Perlis" data-name="Perlis" id="myCheckBox95" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Perlis</label>
            <ul id="navlist">
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="52" data-id="Kiosk 52" data-name="Kiosk 52" id="myCheckBox96" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 52</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <hr/>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" data-id="Negeri Sembilan" data-name="Negeri Sembilan" id="myCheckBox97" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Negeri Sembilan</label>
            <ul id="navlist">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Seremban" data-name="Seremban" id="myCheckBox98" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Seremban</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="53" data-id="Kiosk 53" data-name="Kiosk 53" id="myCheckBox99" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 53</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Nilai" data-name="Nilai" id="myCheckBox100" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Nilai</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="54" data-id="Kiosk 54" data-name="Kiosk 54" id="myCheckBox101" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 54</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <hr/>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" data-id="Kelantan" data-name="Kelantan" id="myCheckBox122" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kelantan</label>
            <ul id="navlist">
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="62" data-id="Kiosk 62" data-name="Kiosk 62" id="myCheckBox123" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 62</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <hr/>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" data-id="Terengganu" data-name="Terengganu" id="myCheckBox124" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Terengganu</label>
            <ul id="navlist">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Terengganu" data-name="Terengganu" id="myCheckBox125" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Terengganu</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="63" data-id="Kiosk 63" data-name="Kiosk 63" id="myCheckBox126" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 63</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" data-id="Kemaman" data-name="Kemaman" id="myCheckBox127" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kemaman</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="kioskMaster[]" value="64" data-id="Kiosk 64" data-name="Kiosk 64" id="myCheckBox128" onchange="checkDisabled(testing);" />Kiosk 64</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Selected items (readable): <span class="selected-readable" id="selected-readable"></span>

    </p>
    <p>Selected items: <span class="selected">[]</span>

    </p>
    <p>Excepted items: <span class="excepted">[]</span>

    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="hidden" name="modeType" value="0">
    <button id="testing" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return submitForm()" disabled>Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div id="myResponse"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, Arun thanks for your answer. You comment is much more appreciate. I will have a try later and get back to you. Less complain and more to solution like others. Thumb Up for you^^

Comment: Hi, Arun i have a problem when user untick the "Terengganu" which is the parent, the submit box unable to go back disabled. Any clue?

Comment: @MarcusTan in the fiddle it seems to work.... are you able to recreate the issue in the fiddle

Comment: I was unable to put all the script on jfiddle, it was too many.

Comment: @MarcusTan do you have any code that check/uncheck the child element when parent is checked/unchecked.. also are you using jQuery

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d0ctjnyL/3/   The parent check function is unable to function on jfiddle, i dono why. From my local here working fine

Comment: @MarcusTan little busy now... will try to look at it later

Comment: Hi, You There? Are you free now?

Comment: @MarcusTan http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d0ctjnyL/4/ - no need to have `checkDisabled` remove the inline `onchange="..."`  from checkbox elements

Comment: Hi, do you have skype or any communication id? Will buy you coffee someday :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79079/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-marcus-tan).